# Query in java code is returning null values but its working fine on ODBC query tool

Tags: java, sql, odbc, jdbc-odbc

With

```
SELECT field2 FROM table1
```

in ODBC query tool I get list of required values, but with the same query from java code I get list of "null" values.

```
SELECT field2 FROM table1 WHERE field2 IS NOT NULL
```

didn't help.

field2 - VARCHAR(255)

part of code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Test");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.exequteQuery("Select field2 FROM table1");
while (resultSet.next)
   System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
```

Comment: and the java code is???

Comment: In addition to java code, Are you sure you have field2 populated i.e. without nulls?

Comment: Can you share the code also?

Comment: Why are you using the slow, buggy and deprecated ODBC bridge? Why don't you use a native JDBC driver?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because i need connect to db by odbc driver

Comment: are you storing null as string in database?

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis no, there are no null strings

Comment: can you post two records with null and without null

Comment: @XemyL Does both ODBC Query Tool and the java code return the same number of results? Run a count query to find out.

Comment: @user32116 yes
SELECT field2 FROM table1 WHERE field2 IS NOT NULL - return the same, when I have SELECT field2 FROM table1
and when I have SELECT field2 FROM table1 WHERE field2 IS NULL - empty list

Comment: @XemyL Ok, could you perhaps show the output from both the java code as well as the query tool? Also, that java code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, my solution of problem:

```
while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(IOUtils.toString(rs.getCharacterStream("field2")));
        }
```

p.s. IOUtils - class from Apache Commons IO
p.s.s. .getBytes() - return me only 255 symbols (there is were more symbols, so i used Reader)